# Validation model in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, backbone.js

I have a model and I'm trying to use `Backbone.Validation` to validate the attributes of the model :

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone","backbone.validation"],function(_ , Backbone, BackboneValidation){
    var CustomerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
         urlRoot: getURL(),
         initialize: function(){
            this.on("error", function(model, error){
               console.log(error);
            });
         },
         validation: function() {
             return {
                Name: {
                  required: true,
                  msg: 'Please enter your name'
                }
             }
         },
         defaults : {
            UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            Name: "",
            Company: "",
            Address: ""
        }
    });
   return CustomerModel;
 });
```

Here is the view :

```
define(["jquery" ,
  "underscore" ,
  "backbone" ,
  "text!templates/Customer/register.html",
  "models/CustomerModel",
  "backbone.validation"
],function($ , _ , Backbone, Register, CustomerModel, BackboneValidation){
var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(){
        Backbone.Validation.bind(this, {
            model: CustomerModel
        });
    },
    events : {
        'click #register' : 'register'
    },
    registerUser : function(e){
        var _customer = new CustomerModel({
            UID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            Name: $("#firstname").val() + $("#lastname").val(),
            Company: "",
            Address: ""
        });
        _customer.save(null, {
            success:function() {
                console.log("successfully register!");
            },
            error : function(){
                console.log("error!");
            }
        });

    },
    render : function(){
        var _register= _.template(Register);
        this.$el.html(_register());
        return this;

    }
});
return RegisterView;
});
```

When I click on button submit without fill in `Name` field, there's no error in my console; otherwise, successfully message is show in console.

I didn't find any sample about calling `backbone.validate` in model initialize function.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm seeing this correct, you are new-ing the model with all the data; and saving null. The validation runs on save, you are not saving anything. Put the name in the save.

Comment: I replaced `null` with the date, and the model still doesn't work.

Comment: But you are not validating the date, you have to `save` the Name to make validation run.

Comment: Ooops sorry my bad, I mean, replaced null with data (Name).